# How to check a file exist or not in unity android?

Tags: android, file, unity-game-engine, file-handling, file-exists

I want to find the file in the path known and if it is pre-existing in android then trigger an event(enable/disable canvas) with it. Here is an example I used -

```
public void FileChk(){

    string filePath = "file://" + Application.temporaryCachePath + "/" + "folder23" + "/" + fileName;

    if (!fileName.Exists)
    {
        //event
    }   
    else
    {       
        //event     
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong here and how do I get this event to trigger when the file exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `System.IO` namespace.

```
public void FileChk()
{
    string filePath = "file://" + Application.temporaryCachePath + "/" + "folder23" + "/" + fileName;

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        // The file exists -> run event
    }
    else
    {
        // The file does not exist -> run event
    }
}
```

The method `bool System.IO.File.Exists(string fileName)` returns a value indicating if the file exists or not.

Comment: will this also work in android export.. I tried but its not working

Comment: I tried debugging but shows no error. Panel.enabled = false; in the exist condition does not work. The file is stored in the correct location

Comment: @Ron Whats the exact path of your file that you are using?

Comment: its the same as above.. I have also made a delete function and it works with the same location

Comment: @Ron It should work fine. I think the error is somewhere on your side.

Comment: I am using this string filePath =  "file://" + Application.temporaryCachePath + "/" + "folder23" + "/" + fileName;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {            
            Panel.enabled = false; 
        }
        else if(!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Panel.enabled = true;
        }

Comment: File.Exists() does not work on correct android paths like Application.streamingAssetsPath in Unity.

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure you imported the **System.IO;** in the beginning of your script, then just be sure to not write a code like this :

```
if (!Directory.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath) + "filename.extention") {}
```

instead, make sure to write your code like this (in your case that you want to check for a file):

```
if (!File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/filename.extention")) {}
```

**Just REMEMBER:** 
**Directory.Exists** checks for folder and **File.Exists** checks for file.

Answer (score 1):

```
File f = new File(this.context.getFilesDir(), "catalogAsset" + this.pk + ".jpeg");

if (f.exists()){
  //EXISTS TODO SOMETHING.
} else {
  //NOT EXISTS TODO SOMETHING.
}
```