# "Menu Component/MaterialUI/Toaster can't be checked because doesn't exist" error but it does exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I try to run my Unity project for Android (not sure if that matters or not) but I get multiple errors from the same source saying "Menu Component/MaterialUI/Toaster can't be checked because doesn't exist". When I look for these files, they do exist in its proper place and I don't see anything wrong with them.

Can anyone help me figure out why it is saying these files don't exist when they do?

Here is the screenshot of my work environment (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiI2A.jpg)

I don't have too much background in Unity, and I can't find this issue anywhere else on the internet. Not sure exactly what I can try. The files in question open fine and there are no errors in the code.

Expected result should be finding these files and not marking them as nonexistent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a file exist or not in unity android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770467/how-to-check-a-file-exist-or-not-in-unity-android)

Comment: @Eliasar this is not a duplicate .. OPs question here seems to be more about compiling issues .. the question is not how to check a file existence on runtime

Comment: @Eliasar no, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @derHugo is correct

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find this issue anywhere else on the internet

There is a most probably related [Issue report](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/selecting-custom-menuitem-from-component-tab-results-in-cant-be-checked-because-doesnt-exist-error-message)

---

A possible hot-fix is provided by ProtoPottyGames:

> just remove the part that says `Component/` in whatever file its erroring on
>
> Bugged Code:
>
> ```
> [MenuItem("Component/Physics/Obi/Obi Particle Renderer", false, 0)]
> ```
>
> Fixed Code:
>
> ```
> [MenuItem("Physics/Obi/Obi Particle Renderer", false, 0)]
> ```

---

Alternatively as described in the docs with newer Unity version one should rather use the [`[AddComponentMenu]` attribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AddComponentMenu.html) instead for better organizing the component menu.

---

So since you have access to the raw script files you should simply search the entire solution in VisualStudio (or whatever you are using) for the according strings like e.g.

```
"Component/MaterialUI/Toaster"
```

and replace it either by

```
[MenuItem("MaterialUI/Toaster")]
```

in order to place it in a separate menu or rather

```
[AddComponentMenu("MaterialUI/Toaster")]
```

in order to still place it in a submenu of component.

It is very likely that these methods will be found in a script within the `MaterualUI/Editor` folder.

---

Another cause for this might be that these are indeed only the check methods (see the bool pparameter for [`[MenuItem]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html)). If you have e.g.

```
[MenuItem("SomeMenu/SomeEntry", true)]
private static bool CanClick()
{
    // return true or false depending on some condition
    return false;
}
```

this is a checker method for an according method like

```
[MenuItem("SomeMenu/SomeEntry")]
private static void DoSomething()
{
    // ...
}
```

Now if this second method doesn't exist or its path string was changed then Unity complains since there is no menu item with the same path to be checked by the first method. This might happen e.g. if they were implemented in different classes (stupid theoretically but possible) and the one with the actual `void` methods was deleted.

---

**Note:** Next thing to worry about would be the warning about you trying to use `new SomeMonoBehaviourClass()` somewhere ...